# Guzzle creating too many TCP connections and causing 502 timeouts - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle, php-curl

When doing load testing with a large amount of concurrent requests on a Laravel endpoint that consumes a 3rd party service using the Guzzle client, it creates a new TCP connection for every request eventually causing 502 timeouts and slowing down the whole application.

I've tried adding the client and the handler as a singleton in the AppServiceProvider, but it didn't make any difference - still does a connection for each request.

Please see below example of using the same handler.

**AppServiceProvider register function:**

```
$curlHandler = new CurlHandler();
$this->app->singleton(HandlerStack::class, function() use ($curlHandler) {
    return HandlerStack::create($curlHandler));
});
```

**Usage in controller:**

```
$client = new Client(['handler' => app(HandlerStack::class)]);
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could assist with this please and provide a possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: How likely is the remote service to update? could you cache the response and use it for subsequent requests for a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @Dale The service updates rapidly so each subsequent request would have to request new data.

Comment: Each PHP request is typically sandboxed. You can't share resources between requests. `singleton` means that the instance is only created once within the same request. If this level of resource sharing is required then you can use something like [Octane](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/octane) or switch to a technology like .NET MVC or Java Spring that are capable of sharing resources across requests. It's probably easier to use [route rate limiting](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#rate-limiting)